# Why are my custom Google Maps icons showing in pc-browsers, but not in Android browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, android, wordpress, google-maps

I have a website with a Google Map on it. This is a Wordpress-site, and each (custom) post on the site has some geographical location meta values, generated through an Advanced Custom Fields' Maps-field.

I have created five custom icons, which are hosted on the same server as the website. The icons to be shown on the map then differs based on another custom value for each post. There are in total appr. 180 markers to be shown simultaneously.

When viewing the rendered map with a computer the custom icons loads as expected.

However, if I view the same page with an Android phone, the custom icons are ignored, and the default red marker(s) loads instead. Why is this?

**Update:**
Additional info:
It *works* as expected on my older Android tablet! It does *not work* on my phone.
The tablet is a Samsung SM-T525 running on Android 4.4.2.
The phone is a Huawei P9 running on Android 7.0.

This is the javascript I am using:

```
(function($) {
  function render_map($el) {
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
    var args = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);
    map.markers = [];
    $markers.each(function() {
      add_marker($(this), map);
    });
    center_map(map);
  }

  function add_marker($marker, map) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));
    var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      icon: icon
    });
    map.markers.push(marker);
    if ($marker.html()) {
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: $marker.html()
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  }

  function center_map(map) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $.each(map.markers, function(i, marker) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
      bounds.extend(latlng);
    });
    if (map.markers.length == 1) {
      map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
      map.setZoom(16);
    } else {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.acf-map').each(function() {
      render_map($(this));
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

This is the relevant php:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'customposttype',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'no_found_rows' => true
);
$mapquery = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $mapquery->have_posts()): ?>
<div class="acf-map" style="height:708px;">
   <?php
      while ($mapquery->have_posts()): $mapquery->the_post();
        $personalmap = get_field( 'personalmap' );
        $status = get_field( 'status' );
        switch ($status) {
            case "variant-one":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-one.png';
                break;
            case "variant-two":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-two.png';
                break;
            case "variant-three":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-three.png';
                break;
            case "variant-four":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-four.png';
                break;
            case "variant-five":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-five.png';
                break;
            default:
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-one.png';

        } ?>
   <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $personalmap['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $personalmap['lng']; ?> "data-icon="<?php echo $markertype; ?>"></div>
   <?php
      endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

-And then it suddenly works. WHY I have no idea! (That is: Why it didn't work (on Android phones) in the first place is beyond my knowlegde...)

I did do some changes though, but I don't understand why they effected this issue.

Javascript:

```
(function($) {
function render_map($el) {
  var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
  var args = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);
  map.markers = [];
  $markers.each(function() {
    add_marker($(this), map);
  });
  center_map(map);
}

function add_marker($marker, map) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));
  var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: icon
  });
  map.markers.push(marker);
  if ($marker.html()) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: $marker.html(),
      maxWidth: 350 // This is added
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {  //This is added
      infowindow.close();
    });
  }
}

function center_map(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  $.each(map.markers, function(i, marker) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });
  if (map.markers.length == 1) {
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(16);
  } else {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.acf-map').each(function() {
    render_map($(this));
  });
});

})(jQuery);
```

The php:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'customposttype',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'no_found_rows' => true
);
$mapquery = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $mapquery->have_posts()): ?>
<div class="acf-map" style="height:708px;">
   <?php
      while ($mapquery->have_posts()): $mapquery->the_post();
        $personalmap = get_field( 'personalmap' );
        $status = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'status', 'true'); //This has changed
        switch ($status) {
            case "variant-one":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-one.png';
                break;
            case "variant-two":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-two.png';
                break;
            case "variant-three":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-three.png';
                break;
            case "variant-four":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-four.png';
                break;
            case "variant-five":
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-five.png';
                break;
            default:
                $markertype = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/custommarker-one.png';

        } ?>
   <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $personalmap['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $personalmap['lng']; ?> "data-icon="<?php echo $markertype; ?>">
        <div class="mapinfo">
            <div class="mapinfo-title">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mapinfo-content">
                <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" height="83" width="83">
                <p><strong><?php the_field('some_value'); ?> texy <?php the_field('smoe_other_value'); ?></strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php
      endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```